# Mysql copy points with srid 0 to srid 4326

Tags: mysql

I am trying to copy points with srid 0 from a table to another table with points srid 4326.

```
INSERT INTO `GeopositionAddresses2`(`Point`)
SELECT
    ST_POINTFROMTEXT(
        CONCAT(
            'POINT(',
            ST_X(`Point`),
            ' ',
            ST_Y(`Point`),
            ')'
        ),
        4326
    ) AS `Point`
FROM
    `GeopositionAddresses`
```

Mysql return
`#3617 - Latitude 142.730815 is out of range in function st_pointfromtext. It must be within [-90.000000, 90.000000].`

and swapping these parameters returns the same error

```
...
            'POINT(',
            ST_Y(`Point`),
            ' ',
            ST_X(`Point`),
            ')
...
```

The table `GeopositionAddresses` has such data:

| ST_X(`Point`) | ST_Y(`Point`) |
| --- | --- |
| 50.570907 | 36.571189 |
| 59.427922619334 | 24.619404439605 |
| 46.980327 | 142.730815 |

`GeopositionAddreses` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `GeopositionAddresses` (
  `Point` point NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

`GeopositionAddreses2` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `GeopositionAddresses` (
  `Point` point NOT NULL SRID 4326
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

DBFiddle example error:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c9e64796dd84c4a07a1f2baac7f2f125

Comment: Latitude is -90 until 90, while longitude is -180 until 180.

```Directly on the opposite side of the earth from the prime meridian is located the 180 meridian. This is the highest longitude possible.```
and
```Since the equator is 0 , the latitude of the north pole, 1/4 of the way around the globe going in a northerly direction, would be 90 N. This is the highest latitude possible.```
http://www.jsu.edu/dept/geography/mhill/phygeogone/latlngprf.html

Seeing your data, Y must be the longitude.

Comment: and it doesn't produce any error on fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ec568ec25dfc15078b523226d382304f

Comment: @Kristian I found an error, when adding points, the coordinates are confused. But now I have 1.5 million such points. How can I fix them? This my error: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c9e64796dd84c4a07a1f2baac7f2f125

Answer (score 0):

Latitude is -90 until 90, while longitude is -180 until 180.

```
Directly on the opposite side of the earth from the prime meridian is located the 180 meridian. This is the highest longitude possible.
```

and

```
Since the equator is 0 , the latitude of the north pole, 1/4 of the way around the globe going in a northerly direction, would be 90 N. This is the highest latitude possible.
```

http://www.jsu.edu/dept/geography/mhill/phygeogone/latlngprf.html

Seeing your data, Y must be the longitude.

X = Longitude, Y = Latitude

since in your data there is: `Y=142.730815` AND range of latitude is -90 until 90, of course it generated error

here is my fiddle to show no error on reproducing your example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ec568ec25dfc15078b523226d382304f

I also copy pasted your fiddle and switched X and Y in the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` statement, and it worked: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ec568ec25dfc15078b523226d382304f

[image: fiddle screenshot]